# For loops with numpy/pandas (iterating over column headers)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe (players) with headers (passes, tackles....)

I am looking to get a correlation coefficient for a few of the columns (not all)

```
for stats in [passes,tackles,shots,saves]:
    cc = np.corrcoef(players.minutes, players.stats)[1,0]
    print cc
```

However, my code returns

```
name 'passes' is not defined
```

because passes is not a defined variable. Is there an easy way to iterate over certain columns for this type of analysis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for stats in ['passes','tackles','shots','saves']:
    cc = np.corrcoef(players['minutes'], players[stats])[1,0]
    print cc
```